# Listview duplicates value

Tags: android, listview

I have dynamic listview in which textview and edittext are two columns. The textview comes with proper data but when i insert the value in edittext in first row then i scroll down the list and in third row the edittext is fill with the first row edittext value. I don't know why this happening. Please help me.

Comment: I have a listview with edittext and i want to enter the value in edittext and after that on button click i get the values of edittext.

Comment: @Niyati Post some code or give more information so we can help you more.

Comment: @IGP thank you for reply....

I use the custom adapter for displaying listview. I use ViewHolder concept in the getview() method of the adapter.I have 5 rows in listview.2 rows are display on the screen at a time. When i enter the value in index 1 - EditText and after i scroll down the index 3 - EditText has the same value which in 1st EditText. I have no idea why its happening. 

And if i do more up and down it changes randomly.

Comment: @Niyati For god's sake! Don't describe the layout, paste the XML and code here...

Comment: @Niyati Tomas is Right because without code nobody can help you so paste some code

Comment: <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Value"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
                </EditText>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide some code so we can better understand the problem. From what i understand this is whats happening.
The adapter generates as many views as can be accomodated on the screen. When you scroll down the list, a new item needs to be generated. This can be done in two ways inside the getView() method shown below.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(convertView==null){  
      //inflater is the layout inflater for the custom view
      convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null); 
      return convertView;
}
else{
    return convertView; //recycled view
    }
}
```

convertView is the view that just went off the screen and is available for recycling. In your case its the convertView which was supposed to be destroyed but is reused again. So the edit text values reappear in the view below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you're inflating a layout for items with have concrete IDs (manually set) and android may think that all listview's items are the same

But if you want real help, paste some code and layouts here... We're not fortune-tellers

Comment: Thank you for reply..but I don't think that happens because the textview comes from database and it renders proper data. There is no repeatation of the data.

Comment: I didn't say anything about possible data duplicities in your database. It's the layout and its views that may have `android:id` attributes set to the same value...

Comment: okk you are right the @+id: in view is same because i repeat it in the listview.

Comment: Please let me know what is the solution for it?

Comment: @Niyati Like I said, I can only guess if you don't show me some code. But I would try to remove `android:id` attributes from your XML layout  (that one with `TextView` and `EditText`). But then you will probably have to find your views using `getChildAt(index)` instead of `findViewById(id)`